# Site collection audit settings: /_catalogs/MaintenanceLogs library missing

Tags: sharepoint-online, auditing, features, reporting

As far as I know there should be MaintenanceLogs library for site collections to store the audit logs in.

[image]

However, recently it seems that some of our site collections are missing /_catalogs/MaintenanceLogs.

Do you know of any site collection features that have to be enabled for this library to be created?

[image]

I already turned on the "Reporting" feature but it didn't change anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learned from Microsoft support that this is an expected behaviour. Newly created site collections are not provisioned with this library any longer as this functionality is available in the O365 Security & Compliance center.

Comment: Turns out that  /_catalogs/MaintenanceLogs is still provisioned with the modern team sites. There is a hidden feature MaintenanceLogs (8c6f9096-388d-4eed-96ff-698b3ec46fc4) that is activated when a modern Team site is created.

Answer (score 2):

If this is expected behavior then why is the ability to configure it in the UI allowing you to get an error message?

Also, something I noticed is that I didn't have audit events from SharePoint in the Security and Compliance center until I turned on auditing for site collections.

I've put in a DCR to Microsoft to see about getting this fixed if anyone cares to help me by upvoting it since they don't seem to think this is a bug.  I mean if you don't want people turning it on, or that capability is elsewhere in your tenant, then why allow people to enable it from their site collection settings?

https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/330318-sharepoint-administration/suggestions/34693603-cannot-enable-site-collection-audit-logging

Comment: I second your point of view and upvoted your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

In order to add a missing /_catalogs/MaintenanceLogs library, we can enable the following hidden feature: **MaintenanceLogs** 8c6f9096-388d-4eed-96ff-698b3ec46fc4.
All new Modern Team sites are supposed to have this feature activated. So if /_catalogs/MaintenanceLogs is missing, it might be a glitch.

This is the PowerShell PnP code that activates the MaintenanceLogs feature that ensues /_catalogs/MaintenanceLogs library is provisioned:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -url "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/ModernTeamSite"
$MaintenanceLogsFeature= "8c6f9096-388d-4eed-96ff-698b3ec46fc4" 
Enable-PnPFeature $MaintenanceLogsFeature
```